# Merging Pandas DataFrames with a rule

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, merge, concatenation

I am trying to merge two DataFrames with common row and column indexes, however, I am expecting entries with similar row and column indexes to exist in both DataFrames.

Is there a way to make a rule to keep the entries in df1 if they are present but if there is no value then to use the value in df2?

so df3 = some operation on df1,df21

Example:

```
  df1 = [[[a],[b],[c]],
         [[ ],[e],[ ]],
         [[g],[h],[i]]]

  df2 = [[[ ],[ ],[ ]],
         [[d],[x],[f]],
         [[y],[z],[z]]]

  df3 = [[[a],[b],[c]],
         [[d],[e],[f]],
         [[g],[h],[i]]]
```

Comment: Please give proper examples of input and expected output.

Comment: `df3 = df1.combine_first(df2)` ?

Comment: @ChrisA thanks this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for pandas df.fillna()::

```
d1 = [['a','b','c'],[None,'e',None],['g','h','i']] 
d2 = [[None,None,None],['d','x','f'],['y','z','z']]
df1,df2 = pd.DataFrame(d1),pd.DataFrame(d2)

df1.fillna(df2)


   0  1  2
0  a  b  c
1  d  e  f
2  g  h  i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
df1[df1.isnull()] = df2.values
```